# how to set build output path directory of SSIS package project?

Tags: c#, ssis, scheduled-tasks

I have 2 projects

1. SSIS package project (doing lot of stuff connecting to FTP server and downloading files to file system then writing those files to SQL database)
2. Window service project (on a scheduled time load the SSIS package and execute it)

Problem:-
How, do I set the output path directory of SSIS project to the bin of my Window service project?

Comment: The easiest way is to install BI Developer Extensions:  https://bideveloperextensions.github.io/. It has a great "Deploy SSIS Package" that allows you to set an arbitrary folder as the deployment path and deploy directly from VS/BIDS. Barring that, you'd need to create a deployment utility as part of the SSIS build process. I have a feeling that neither of these options are what you're actually looking for though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it, but a little evolved way.

1. In your FTP task, set your local path from variable. To do this, specify *IsLocalPathVariable=true* in FTP task properties, and set some string variable storing local path, say, *[User::LocalFTPPath]*.
2. Define package property (if FTP path is specific to certain package) or project property (if this FTP path is for the whole project) of type string.
3. For variable *[User::LocalFTPPath]* set variable Expression to @[Package::< path parameter>] or @[Project::< path parameter>].
4. On the service side - when it runs some package - specify the properr value for ftp path parameter.